# Turtlebot3 - how to work with various OpenCR sensors and actions

Tags: turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The OpenCR board has various sensors and actions: User LED x 4 : LD3 (red), LD4 (green), LD5 (blue), Gyroscope 3Axis, Accelerometer 3Axis, Magnetometer 3Axis (MPU9250), User button x 2.

What's the best way to access them from a ROS node? I would like to be able to read the gyro, accelerometer, magnetometer, and user buttons, and activate the LEDs.

I see that Turtlebot3 Burger core source for OpenCR in Arduino IDE, there are 5 publishers and I see their message types https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_msgs/blob/master/msg/SensorState.msg but I can't find the actual code that publishes. I've downloaded what I think is all the source code but can't find the code that actually publishes. I must be blind!

Can someone indicate to me where that code is and/or where it is documented?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272779/turtlebot3---how-to-work-with-various-opencr-sensors-and-actions/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the Turtlebot3 Burger core source for [OpenCR](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/wiki) in Arduino IDE, there are 5 publishers.
One of them is sensor_state_pub that publishes button status, voltage level, encoder values on "sensor_state" topic.
(https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_msgs/blob/master/msg/SensorState.msg)
Similarly, imu_pub publishes IMU readings from OpenCR with "imu" topic.
You can subscribe these topics in order to receive data from OpenCR.

However, there is no subscriber in the OpenCR firmware nor publisher in RPi 3 Turtlebot3 source for LED control.
The latest OpenCR firmware already utilizes USER1~4 LEDs for TXD, RXD, Low Battery and ROS Connect indicator.
If you want to use these LEDs for other purpose from RPi3, you need to create publisher for LED topic in the RPi 3 and subscriber for the same in the OpenCR(with Arduino IDE) to control LED.

========Appended Answer==========
I'm sorry for the unclear explanation about the OpenCR firmware.
In Arduino IDE, if you opened turtlebot3_core from "File > Examples > turtlebot3 > turtlebot3_burger > turtlebot3_core", the "turtlebot3_core" tab will be opened in default.
In the same file, go to line #313 where you can find "void publishSensorStateMsg(void)" function.
This function is called within the main loop (line # 203) of the code.

---

Originally posted by [Will Son](https://answers.ros.org/users/32218/will-son/) with karma: 66 on 2017-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-10-22**:
I've edited the original question with some additional details.